# Configure Spring Boot Authentication / Login with MyBatis + H2

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, h2, mybatis

I have a **Spring Boot application** that uses **MyBatis** with **H2**.
I know I can inject the `@Mapper` wherever I need, to call the database operation through **MyBatis**.

What I don't know is where or what should I configure/override in **Spring Boot** to make sure I receive the login information that the user just entered? So if the user exists, I can redirect them to wherever I want, otherwise show an error.

All the examples I find work only with static username/password through overriding:

`public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`.

Also, how and what do I for logout?

Comment: It's a broad question, so I just share a link to the [demo application](https://github.com/kazuki43zoo/mybatis-spring-boot-jpetstore) built using Spring Boot + MyBatis. It uses Spring Security for authentication. The backend is HSQLDB which is not that different than H2.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but it doesn't have what I was looking for. I figured out a way, I'll post the answer in a few hours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To setup authentication, you will need to implement your own `AuthenticationProvider`, and `@Override` the `authenticate` method per your requirements.

For my case, I had to `@Autowired` the **MyBatis** Mapper interface, and use this mapper (Make DB calls) in the `authenticate` method to decide whether or not to authenticate the user.